# FFMPEG image concatenation giving different results based on colors in PNG file

Tags: ffmpeg, png, concatenation

I am using the following code to take a number of PNGs of varying durations and the overlaying them over another video.

```
ffmpeg  -safe -0 -f concat -i  overlap-png.txt 
-i mainvideo.MOV -filter_complex "[1]scale=1920:-1[1v];[0:v]fps=30[0v];[1v][0v]overlay=0:0"  
-c:v libx264 -profile:v baseline -pix_fmt yuv420p 
-level 3.1 -y  finishedvideo.mp4
```

However, I have discovered something very odd.  The PNG files referred to in the .txt file are all primarily transparent except for a bar at the bottom that is around 300 pixels or so.  IF that bar is dark gray, everything works perfectly fine.

IF that bar is red, many of the images are dropped or frames are possibly dropped.

Also, I notice that the script runs differently depending on whether the bar is red or dark gray.  If it is red, there is more line by line processing and if it is dark gray, it appears the same encode happens in one line of processing.

Comment: Post the log for `ffmpeg  -safe -0 -f concat -i  overlap-png.txt -vf showinfo -f null - `

Comment: Posted.  Thanks for popping over.  Thought, since the scope changed, would post a new question.

Comment: The 3rd log is for the original command, not the one in my comment. The 4th log shows up blank.

Comment: my apologies.  One moment.

Comment: @Gyan ok I updated those links above and they should go to the right spots now.  Thanks much for your help! :)

Comment: The images have different pixel formats. Run `ffmpeg  -safe -0 -f concat -i  overlap-png.txt -copyts -c:v png -pix_fmt rgba -vsync 0 overlap.mov ` and then overlay with that.

Comment: So I am creating each of these images with ImageMagick.  Is there any way I can make them have the same pixel format so that I can do it the other way?

Comment: Don't know the IM flags for that.

Comment: Curious, where can I see the different pixel formats used in the images?  Thanks so much for your help!

Comment: This is working good for me.  The speed is good on the first encode, so I am good with it.  If you want to leave it as an answer, I will vote up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not all the PNGs have the same pixel format. I see it alternating between rgba and pal8 (8-bit palette). When an input changes its properties mid-way, ffmpeg reinitializes filters. When that happens, any buffered frames are dropped.

There is an option, starting with ffmpeg 4.2, to prevent reinitialization. In this case, the pixel format has to be manually harmonized. For older versions, an intermediate version can be created with the same pixel format.

Starting with ffmpeg 4.2, you can run

```
ffmpeg  -safe 0 -f concat -reinit_filter 0 -i overlap-png.txt 
-i mainvideo.MOV -filter_complex "[1]scale=1920:-1[1v];[0:v]null,format=rgba[0v];[1v][0v]overlay=0:0"  
-c:v libx264 -profile:v baseline -pix_fmt yuv420p 
-level 3.1 -y  finishedvideo.mp4
```

For older versions, first create an intermediate file,

```
ffmpeg -safe 0 -f concat -i overlap-png.txt -copyts -c:v png -pix_fmt rgba -vsync 0 overlap.mov
```

and then run your original command.

Comment: Great answer.  Thanks so much Gyan.